# Disable compiler warnings per line

Tags: f#, compiler-warnings

Is it possible to disable compiler warnings for specific lines?

In C#, this works:

```
[Obsolete]
class Old { }

#pragma warning disable 612
    var oldWithoutWarning = new Old();
#pragma warning restore 612
    var oldWithWarning = new Old();
```

This would be very useful for disabling incomplete pattern matches warnings, especially when a function accepts a particular case of a DU.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the warnings are turned off per-file (or possibly 'from here to the bottom of the file') when using `#nowarn`.  (Or per compilation/project when using project properties / `--nowarn` command-line.)

Comment: Can this be a feature request? :-)

Comment: Yeah, we probably already have one logged, but I don't see us doing it any time soon; there is a very long list of 'nice to have' features, and we barely have time to get to all the essentials.  If it really bothers you, I suggest putting the few implementations that need to turn off this warning in a separate file, and use `#nowarn` on that file.

Comment: BTW - Where should F# feature requests be sent/posted? Is [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) under Visual Studio the right place?

Comment: Use Connect for bugs; the user voice site is now best for feature suggestions: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio

Comment: F# no longer uses the Visual Studio user voice; it has its own. This particular feature is requested here: https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6085102-allow-f-compiler-directives-like-nowarn-to-span

Comment: F# language suggestions moved to GitHub https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/278

Answer (score 1):

Since everything is an expression in F# it's not hard to pull out a line or a part of a line and put it in it's own file.

Example of my issue, where `::` pattern matching warned about empty list possiblity, but my state passed to `Seq.fold` always has a list with at least one item.

```
module FoldBookmarks
#nowarn "25"

let foldIntoBookmarks: (string * int * int) seq -> XamlReport.PDF.Bookmark seq = 
        Seq.fold (fun ((tl,pl,acc)::l) (t,p,_) -> (t,acc,p+acc)::((tl,pl,acc)::l)) [("",0,1)]
        >> Seq.map(fun (x,y,_) -> PDF.Bookmark(Title=x, PageNumber= System.Nullable(y)))
```